What does Rust (for Windows) need Windows build tools/Visual Studio for?
I understand that Rust needs Windows build tools when you are interested in developing for Windows (easy example here: display a window, Windows forms/UI style, etc...).
But, when not dealing with Windows development (e.g. a web server, a backend application, a web scrapping script, etc...), does it still needs the Windows build tools?
Even for a "Hello World" program?
I feel like the ~10gb to ~20gb that Windows build tools requires on disk space for Rust to work is a hard stopper for many people, and I want to know if it's 100% required or only when developing specifically for Windows.
In my case I decided to go with WSL + build-essential which is about 200mb

https://users.rust-lang.org/t/why-do-i-need-microsoft-c-build-tools/18581

From the rustup book on MSVC prerequesites:

To compile programs into an exe file, Rust requires a linker, libraries and Windows API import libraries

So the Visual Studio build tools are required for creating the final executable and providing libraries for Windows syscalls. The Rust compiler is only a portion of the full build and needs to use a separate linker: link.exe provided by the build tools. It is not related to Windows desktop interface development. I believe this manual step is required because Rust itself is not allowed to distribute these tools.
If you are concerned about developer disk space there are instructions for only the minimal required components (depending on your local system):

If you’d like a more minimal install (and won’t be doing C++ development) then you can use the "Individual Components" tab to select just the essentials, which are:

MSVC v143 - VS 2022 C++ x64/x86 build tools (Latest)
Windows 11 SDK (10.0.22621.0)


I believe the disk size is still around 3-4Gb.

But that only applies to the *-msvc targets; there are other ways to build for Windows. The general rustup documentation for Windows says:

[T]here are two ABIs in use on Windows: the native (MSVC) ABI used by Visual Studio, and the GNU ABI used by the GCC toolchain. Which version of Rust you need depends largely on what C/C++ libraries you want to interoperate with: for interop with software produced by Visual Studio use the MSVC build of Rust; for interop with GNU software built using the MinGW/MSYS2 toolchain use the GNU build.

Using a different target like *-pc-windows-gnu will use the MinGW/MYSYS2 toolchain instead and does not require the Visual Studio build tools though as noted you may need to exercise caution when stepping out of the Rust ecosystem. I do not know the install size of this route (@Jmb reports "The *-pc-windows-gnu targets include the required GNU tools, so they don't require to install anything else but they are bigger: 775M as opposed to 372M for the msvc target on my PC today").

Or as you've found, you could circumvent that by using WSL1 which has a compatibility layer for linux executables or WSL2 which uses a fully separate virtualized kernel for building for and running linux executables. However, I am skeptical that this is less of a burden on your system resources as you seem to think.

The *-pc-windows-gnu targets include the required GNU tools, so they don't require to install anything else (but they are bigger: 775M as opposed to 372M for the msvc target on my PC today).

Also they use the same ABI, so final executables are fully interoperable. The most obvious difference is the object file format, which may be an issue when using 3rd party tools (e.g. you can't use CUDA on the GNU target because NVIDIA's tools only support MSVC object files).

@Jmb I was thinking that was the case, but I was unsure and simply going off of the rustup documentation wording. And thanks for deducing those install size numbers.

Thanks for your response and thanks @Jmb for the added info.
I've yet much to learn about linkers/build tools. Coming from a NodeJS and PHP environment, dealing with "low level" stuff and compatibility layers can be difficult...
About using WSL, I know it's probably a bigger burden than installing the required tools for Windows, but I'm already using it for other projects in my daily basis so in my case it simplified the process a lot.

Following this discussion on users.rust-lang.org you need:

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64 (C++ build tools, cl.exe, linker etc.)
Microsoft.Component.VC.Runtime.UCRTSDK (Universal C Runtime, provides standard C library functions)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows11SDK.26100 [or whichever version is recent] (for integration with Windows API, DirectX, so actually not strictly necessary)

I download the Tools for Visual Studio 2022 (vs_BuildTools.exe) bootstrapper and then use cmdline to download the minimally required packages (workloads in MS speech) for compiling rust into the folder vs_installer:
C:\Apps>vs_BuildTools.exe --layout vs_installer --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64 --add Microsoft.Component.VC.Runtime.UCRTSDK --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows11SDK.26100

And after downloading you can install from that folder offline via:
C:\Apps\vs_installer> vs_BuildTools.exe --noWeb --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64 --add Microsoft.Component.VC.Runtime.UCRTSDK --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows11SDK.26100

If you don't care about the offline install, you can also only run the last command without the --noWeb flag. FYI, a list of workloads that can be downloaded/installed in this way can be found here.
The size of these packages/workloads/(the vs_installer folder) after donwload (not the installed size) is 1.4Gb.
